# Is it possible to use named-pipes in Theano?

Tags: python, named-pipes, theano

Does `Theano` support `named-pipes` [for both reading\writing]? What about reading\writing files in general?

Comment: Theano itself doesn't really do any file I/O. If you could expand your question to add more information we may be able to help. What data do you want to read/write? Can you share some code for what you've got right now and more detail on how you would like it to work?

Comment: Thanks @DanielRenshaw  Basically what I need is to read\write a numpy matrix\vector [binary coded].
Very simple usage will be something like:

    `buffer = mypipe.read();  
    vec = struct.unpack(message_format, buffer);  
    # Now, do some convertion to numpy matrix\arrays with "vec"`

Answer (score 0):

If you're familiar with how to to do the I/O using Python and/or numpy then that's all you need. Just pass the numpy data to the compiled Theano function (or first store the numpy array in a shared variable if that's what the Theano computation expects).

Theano itself doesn't do any I/O. Inputs to compiled Theano functions should be numpy arrays (or castable to numpy arrays) and the outputs of a compiled Theano function will also be numpy arrays. How you read the input arrays into memory, or write the output arrays elsewhere, is none of Theano's concern, just use Python and/or numpy as normal.

There's an example using named pipes in Python [here](http://www.roman10.net/named-pipe-in-linux-with-a-python-example/).

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough.
I'm using scan, and would like to invoke an external piece of (C) code at each step of the loop (without exiting the graph).
I can use `as_op`, but only for Python code.
The question is whether i can wrap pipes I/O inside a new C Op for example? something like: `... c_code="""mkfifo(myfifo, 0666); fd = open(myfifo, O_WRONLY); write(fd, "Hi", sizeof("Hi")); close(fd); """` @Daniel

Comment: What about gradients? Theano can't automatically differentiate arbitrary C code. If you don't need gradients then Theano probably isn't the right tool. If you're willing to implement the gradients yourself then yes you can create a custom op that does whatever I/O you want.

Comment: I'm using a basic Reinforcement Learning setup, where an agent interacts with the environment. I use scan to play a full episode. I have to use it because it allows me to propagate information backwards in time. However i can't model the environment using theano nor Python (and wrap it inside `as_op`). It's too complicated and is also given to me as an external emulator. The good thing is that I don't care about its gradients. Adding a pipe op to allow the graph to talk with the outside world is what i yearn for. I appreciate any guidance on how to tackle this. @Daniel